# Safe to store access details in a session?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

**Background**

I am about to create a website which will have a registration/login area. After the user has logged in he/she will have the ability to buy one or many modules which consist of static content regarding a topic. Of course the security on these modules is important as I want to make sure only people who have bought the package have acccess to the relevent modules.

**Problem**

Do you think its a good idea to store the information in a session about which user has access to which package once they have logged in so I only make a single call to the database to find out.

**OR**

I go to the database everytime they access a particular module to make sure they have access to that module

**OR**

I do both

**OR**

there is an another way I have completely missed...

Any advice will be great. I am trying to get a balance between performance and security.

Thanks

Comment: If such a simple query could come even near to creating a performance problem, you would most likely get far bigger problems in other areas where you need to access serious amounts of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you store the information in the session, it might get outdated wrt. to the database. That is, if module ownership expires, or it can be cancelled through other means, it might still be present in someone's session. Whether that's a problem or even a feature, is up to you.

However, this is "premature optimization". Unless you can prove (prove!) that this is going to be a performance problem, I wouldn't spend any more time than strictly necessary on it.

Comment: As alex said spend time on this only if hitting the database would really take you away from your performance benchmark! And if it does you need to consider updating the info in the session if the user prvlgs change because of user actions ( easy bit) and if the user privlg change because of other factors (subscription expired, system changes like rules of subscription change, any batch running on your system etc etc etc.)